# addEventListener: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

On my Chrome browser, I've got an error:

> undefined is not a function
> at the line: dom.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false);

I'm learning webGL and here is my actual code:

```
<html>

<head>

<?php include "header.php"?>
<title>Learning WebGL</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/glmatrix/glMatrix.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../three.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../requestAnimationFrame.js">    </script>
<script>

var renderer = null,
        scene = null,
        camera = null,
        cube = null,
        animating = false;

function onload()
{
        var container = document.getElementById("container");

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
        renderer.setSize(container.offsetWidth, container.offsetHeight);
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, container.offsetWidth/container.offsetHeight, 1, 4000);
        camera.position.set(0,0,3);

        var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
        light.position.set(0,0,1);
        scene.add(light);

        var mapUrl = "/test.jpg";
        var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(mapUrl);

        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: map});

        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1);

        cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        cube.rotation.x = Math.PI / 5;
        cube.rotation.y = Math.PI / 5;

        scene.add(cube);

        addMouseHandler();

        run();
}

function run()
{
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        if(animating){
                cube.rotation.y -= 0.01;
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(run);
}

function addMouseHandler()
{
        var mydom = renderer.domElement;
        mydom.addEventlistener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
}

function onMouseUp(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        animating = !animating;
}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="onload();">
        <?php include "navigation.php"?>
        <div id="container" style="width:95%; height:95%; position:absolute;">
        </div>
        <div id="prompt" style="width:95%; height:6%; bottom:0; position:absolute;">
                Click to animate the cube
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I've tried changing the variable name from `dom` to `mydom` but that doesn't help.

Comment: Hi Frederic, I Just put my own code and eliminated the typo. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. From your edit, I can see you call `mydom.addEventlistener()` instead of `mydom.addEventListener()`, capital `L`. That might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Hi Frederic, that solves my problem :) I'm new to javascript so still suffering from the naming conventions. Thank you!